# Azure Sphere UART no reading 0x00 from serial device

Tags: serial-port, uart, posix-api, azure-sphere

I am reading data from a device through the serial port. I am using a Max3232 converter RS232 to TTL. The odd thing here is that when I use the read function to retrieve the data received by the UART, it eliminates all the 0x00 bytes.

I have used the same converter to read data from the same device using both Arduino Mega and Raspberry PI 3 B+. With both I can read the 0x00 values.

**Reading with Arduino and Raspberry**

f7 00 00 15 10 22 00 02 28 02 00 00

f2 16 06 00 00 00 00 67 63 02 45 43

**Same readings with Azure Sphere**

f7 15 10 22 02 28 02

f2 16 06 67 63 02 45 43

Am I missing some setting?

Comment: Are you seeing this behavior on HighLevel or RealTime App? Can you repro this using the samples? [UART_HighLevelApp](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sphere-samples/tree/master/Samples/UART/UART_HighLevelApp) or [UART_RTApp_MT3620_BareMetal](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sphere-samples/tree/master/Samples/UART/UART_RTApp_MT3620_BareMetal) ? Thanks

Comment: What library do you use for controlling UART peripheral?